# Exposure compensation button stuck

Tags: nikon, nikon-d5600

Today I noticed that the exposure compensation button on my Nikon D5600 was stuck.

First I thought that the whole camera was malfunctioning because I couldn't review my photos, I couldn't change the focus point, when turning the wheel in manual mode it would change the aperture instead of the shutter speed etc... I was able to take photos, but the screen would remain black all the time.

Only a few minutes later I noticed that the aforementioned button "sunk" a bit, like some invisible finger was holding it down. I tried pressing and releasing it a few times and eventually I managed to "unstuck" it, so now the camera is working properly. I can use the button, but it still doesn't feel normal, there's no that "click" sound when I press it, it feels very soft (not sure if I explained it well).

Is there any quick hack to fix it, or should I take the camera to the service?